# Excel formula to match multiple dates across 2 columns, returning Yes or No

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will match dates across column A and B in the below table. There are over 100000 results to match in each of my tables.

If specific date appears in both columns, then it returns with 'Yes' statement. If it only appears in one column, than 'No'.

[image]

I tried to use the below formula but it doesn't return the correct output:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A:$A)=0, "Yes", "No")
```

The correct results should be as in column C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would conditional formatting work for you?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately, it will not as I need to build this formula into VBA script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick, name what you want to display.

The logic is this: It counts if the criteria exist in Column A. When no matches is found (=0) it give "Don't exist in Column A".

`=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)=0, "Don't exist in Column A","Yes")`

So in your case when we apply the formula it will look like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A;B3)=0, "No", "Yes")
```

[image]

Notice in the picture I use "`;`" as delimiter since I have a Nordic Excel version. US will probably use "`,`".

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)=0, "Don't exist in Column A","Yes")` This works perfectly. Thanks Wizhi

Comment: aahahah, you made me worried for a second :D!!! Great. Glad to help. Take care :)!!!!!. I added the both of them to make other people understand the logic of the formula (what it looks at :P)

Answer (score 3):

## A Faster Excel Version

Referring to the formula `=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)=0,"No","Yes")`

### Looks like the same but its much faster.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0)),"No","Yes")
```

On first glance, match **should** be faster since it cannot count, but of course the reason is probably in the following logic:
**COUNT** searches the whole range to calculate the **COUNT** and then the **IF** 'decides' if it is **0** or not.
**MATCH** searches the range only until it finds the **MATCH** and when found the **IF** 'decides via the **ISERROR** function' if it is TRUE or FALSE. If the matches would be at the bottom of the range, maybe the speed gap could be disregarded, but they aren't.

Rearranging the formulas like

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0))),"Yes","No")
```

or

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)<>0,"Yes","No")`
```

doesn't change a thing. **MATCH** still searches until a match is found, and **COUNT** still counts in the whole range.

So to conclude:

**MATCH** is the '**Excel**' way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But I have a feeling that both formulas might be useless in your case of hundreds of thousands of rows. Investigate and give us some feedback how fast they are.

Answer (score 1):

If you need result when the *Audit date* column to match with *date* column and *date* column to match with *Audit date* then use

```
=if((countif(B:B,A2)+countif(A:A,B2))<>0,"Yes","No")
```

If you need result when *Audit date* match with the *date* column then use:

```
=if((countif(A:A,B2))<>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Try this one please :if((countif(A:A,B1))<>0,"Yes","No")

Comment: Something must be wrong with this formula as it doesn't return any results. Thanks

Comment: It works here - Please check [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CwM7B4tcn-BFujR0nyCXdckh_RM1on2CFuaBgdoTZIk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `=if((countif(A:A,B2))<>0,"Yes","No")`