# Search a column using entries from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Columns A:D are First Name, Last Name, Address, City. I have about 85 rows of information.

I'm trying to determine if a CITY (Column D) occurs in my list of cities (on another sheet, about 150 rows). It can provide me this answer in say, Column E.

I know `VLOOKUP` won't work because I need it to tell me ALL occurrences of the city name on multiple rows. I've tried to make `INDEX-MATCH` fit, but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I need (or **if** it can do what I need). I thought `SEARCH` would help, but the results don't seem to match reality (I can find entries).

Is there a formula that can do this for me? Basically, I need to know which of the entries match my separate list of cities

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COUNTIF()`? (Adjust `G2:G4` to the separate list of cities you have)

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$2:$G$4,D2),"Is in the list","Is NOT in the list")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup will work, but it is not the most efficient way.

```
=if(iserror(vlookup(A1,'the other sheet'!B:B,1,false)),"not found", "found")
```

Index/Match will work, but you only need the Match part, anyway

```
=if(isnumber(match(A1,'the other sheet'!B:B,0)),"found","not found")
```

The Countif suggested by BruceWayne is the most efficient formula.

Comment: It is unclear what the OP is asking for, due to "ALL occurences", but if it is what you two are suggesting, I would strongly disagree. The Match function should be more efficient. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034707/excel-formula-to-match-multiple-dates-across-2-columns-returning-yes-or-no/53045040#53045040)